# Does any one have an idea about how to set password to existing pdf using openpdf java lib?

Tags: java, spring, openpdf

how to set password to existing PDF  using OpenPdf java lib?
I have tried by below code but that is created new pdf with no content

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class PasswordProtectedPDF {
  public static final String ENCRYPTED_PDF = "F://knpcode//result//OpenPDF//PP.pdf";
  // User and owner password
  final static String USER_PASSWORD = "user";
  final static String OWNER_PASSWORD = "owner";
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Document doc = new Document();
      PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(ENCRYPTED_PDF));
      // set password, user permissions and encryption
      writer.setEncryption(USER_PASSWORD.getBytes(), OWNER_PASSWORD.getBytes(), PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128); 
      doc.open();
 
     
      doc.close();
      writer.close();
    } catch (DocumentException | FileNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose to "set a password"? Do you want to avoid an OPENING without password or do you want to set PERMISSIONS (e.g. printing or copying allowed) ?

Comment: my purpose is to set password to the existing pdf

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding, but you want to set password for WHAT? Again: Do you want to avoid an OPENING without password or do you want to set PERMISSIONS (e.g. printing or copying allowed) ?

Comment: to avoid opening without password

Comment: please see my comment to answer of @Rahul Singh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add password to a new PDF, we use **PdfWriter.setEncryption()** method.

**PdfStamper API is used when we need to protect existing PDF**. While instantiating PdfStamper, it accepts source file as PdfReader and destination file as OutputStream. PdfStamper can add some extra content in PDF while writing to destination file. PdfStamper.setEncryption uses the same arguments as PdfWriter.setEncryption while setting the encryption to existing PDF.

Have updated your code to use PDFStamper instead of PDFWriter.

```
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;
    import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
    
    public class PasswordProtectedPDF {
      // User and owner password
      final static String USER_PASSWORD = "user";
      final static String OWNER_PASSWORD = "owner";
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
          File f = new File("F://knpcode//result//OpenPDF//ENCRYPTED_PP.pdf");
          FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
          PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("F://knpcode//result//OpenPDF//PP.pdf");
          PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, out);
          
          // set password, user permissions and encryption
          stamper.setEncryption(USER_PASSWORD.getBytes(), OWNER_PASSWORD.getBytes(), PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);

          // Don't forget to add this line as no bytes are written to that output stream up until you close the PdfStamper instance. 
          stamper.close();

        } catch ( IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: PDF header signature not found.
 at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PRTokeniser.checkPdfHeader(Unknown Source)
 at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(Unknown Source)
 at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.example.demo.pdf.PasswordProtectedPDF.main(PasswordProtectedPDF.java:30)

Comment: @user13917944: The program above is working as it restricts the access to the file AND only allows printing. When you receive  the "PDF header signature not found" exception then your pdf file is faulty. Please try with another pdf-file as input.

Comment: its working thank you so much@Rahul Singh @MichaelFehr

Comment: What is the encryption algorithm used to encrypt the PDF? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Google "java openpdf password example" I found this website: https://knpcode.com/java-programs/password-protected-pdf-using-openpdf-java/ with some information about your question.

Here are two sample programs (just copy/pasted them, not test). Don't forget to **include Bouncy Castle** as security provider.

Encrypt ("secure") a PDF:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class PasswordProtectedPDF {
  public static final String ENCRYPTED_PDF = "F://knpcode//result//OpenPDF//PP.pdf";
  // User and owner password
  final static String USER_PASSWORD = "user";
  final static String OWNER_PASSWORD = "owner";
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Document doc = new Document();
      PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(ENCRYPTED_PDF));
      // set password, user permissions and encryption
      writer.setEncryption(USER_PASSWORD.getBytes(), OWNER_PASSWORD.getBytes(), PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128); 
      doc.open();
      Paragraph para = new Paragraph("Password protected PDF where only content printing is permitted content can't be copied.");
      doc.add(para);
      doc.close();
      writer.close();
    } catch (DocumentException | FileNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Reading Password protected PDF using OpenPDF:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor;

public class ReadPDF {
  // PDF to be read
  public static final String READ_PDF = "F://knpcode//result//OpenPDF//PP.pdf";
  final static String OWNER_PASSWORD = "owner";
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PdfReader pdfreader = null;
    try {
      pdfreader = new PdfReader(READ_PDF, OWNER_PASSWORD.getBytes());
      // get pages in PDF
      int pages = pdfreader.getNumberOfPages();
      PdfTextExtractor pdfTextExtractor = new PdfTextExtractor(pdfreader);
      // Iterate through pages to read content
      for(int i = 1; i <= pages; i++) {
        // Extract content of each page
        String contentOfPage = pdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(i, true);
        System.out.println(contentOfPage );
      }         
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
      if(pdfreader != null) {
        pdfreader.close();
      }
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried but original content is missing , displays "Password protected PDF where only content printing is permitted content can't be copied." only